# How can I find the first el-table with css selector?

Tags: css, selenium-webdriver, css-selectors

```
<div class="el-table-box" v-if="!specialAnnounce">
                        <el-table ref="notice-table" v-loading="loading" :data="dataList" @sort-change="sortChange">
                            <template slot="empty">
                                <div class="loading" v-if="dataList.length == 0 && loading">
                                    加载中...
                                </div>
                                <div v-if="dataList.length == 0 && !loading" class="no-data">
                                    <img src="http://static.cninfo.com.cn/new/img/announce/no-data.png" alt="">
                                    <p>暂无数据！</p>
                                </div>
                            </template>

                            <el-table-column width="100" prop="secCode" sortable="custom" label="代码">
                                <template slot-scope="scope">
                                    <a class="ahover" target="_blank" :href="'/new'+ '/disclosure/stock?stockCode=' + scope.row.secCode + '&orgId=' + scope.row.orgId">
                                        <span class="code">{{scope.row.secCode}}</span>
                                    </a>
                                </template>
                            </el-table-column>
                            <el-table-column width="180" prop="secName" label="简称">
                                <template slot-scope="scope">
                                    <a class="ahover" target="_blank" :href="'/new'+ '/disclosure/stock?stockCode=' + scope.row.secCode + '&orgId=' + scope.row.orgId">
                                        <span :title="scope.row.secName" class="code delete-hl" v-html="scope.row.secName.length>8?scope.row.secName.slice(0,8)+'...':scope.row.secName"></span>
                                    </a>
                                </template>
                            </el-table-column>
                            <el-table-column prop="announcementTitle" label="公告标题">
                                <template slot-scope="scope">
                                <span class="ahover">
                                    <a v-html="scope.row.announcementTitle" target="_blank" :href="linkLastPage(scope.row)"></a>
                                    <span v-show="checkDocType(scope.row.adjunctType)" class="icon-f"><i class="iconfont" :class="[checkDocType(scope.row.adjunctType)]"></i></span>
                                </span>
                                </template>
                            </el-table-column>
                            <el-table-column width="150" align="left" prop="announcementTime" sortable="custom" label="公告时间">
                                <template slot-scope="scope">
                                    <span class="date">{{fomatDate(scope.row.announcementTime, 'yyyy-MM-dd HH:mm')}}</span>
                                </template>
                            </el-table-column>
                        </el-table>
                    </div>
                    <div v-if="specialAnnounce">
                        <div class="el-table-box">
                            <el-table ref="notice-table" :row-class-name="rowClassCb" @expand-change="expandRowChange" v-loading="loading" :data="dataList2" @sort-change="sortChange">
                                <template slot="empty">
                                    <div class="loading" v-if="dataList2.length == 0 && loading">
                                        加载中...
                                    </div>
                                    <div v-if="dataList.length == 0 && !loading" class="no-data">
                                        <img src="http://static.cninfo.com.cn/new/img/announce/no-data.png" alt="">
                                        <p>暂无数据！</p>
                                    </div>
                                </template>
                                <template v-if="actMarket == 'fund'">
                                    <el-table-column type="expand"></el-table-column>
                                </template>
                                <el-table-column prop="announcementTitle" label="公告标题">
                                    <template slot-scope="scope">
                                        <span class="ahover" v-if="actMarket == 'fund'">
                                            <a v-html="(scope.row.secName && scope.row.secName.split(',').length > 0 ? (scope.row.secName.split(',')[0] + ' : ') : '') +  scope.row.announcementTitle" target="_blank" :href="linkLastPage(scope.row)"></a>
                                            <span v-show="checkDocType(scope.row.adjunctType)" class="icon-f"><i class="iconfont" :class="[checkDocType(scope.row.adjunctType)]"></i></span>
                                        </span>
                                        <span class="ahover" v-if="actMarket != 'fund'">
                                            <a v-html="(scope.row.secName ? (scope.row.secName + ' : ') : '') +scope.row.announcementTitle" target="_blank" :href="linkLastPage(scope.row)"></a>
                                            <span v-show="checkDocType(scope.row.adjunctType)" class="icon-f"><i class="iconfont" :class="[checkDocType(scope.row.adjunctType)]"></i></span>
                                        </span>

                                        <div class="fundNames" v-if="actMarket == 'fund' && scope.row.fundsList && scope.row.fundsList.length > 1 && scope.row.showFunds">
                                            <br/>
                                            <span class="relafund">关联基金：</span>
                                            <div class="funds">
                                                <el-tag class="jump-tag" :title="item.secname" v-for="(item,index) in scope.row.fundsList"><a :href="'/new'+ '/disclosure/stock?stockCode=' +item.seccode + '&orgId=' + item.ogrId">{{item.secname &&　item.secname.length > 10 ? item.secname.slice(0,7) + '...' + item.secname.slice(item.secname.length -2,item.secname.length) : item.secname}}</a></el-tag>
                                            </div>
                                        </div>
                                    </template>
                                </el-table-column>
                                <el-table-column width="150" align="left" prop="announcementTime" sortable="custom" label="公告时间">
                                    <template slot-scope="scope">
                                        <span class="date">{{fomatDate(scope.row.announcementTime, 'yyyy-MM-dd HH:mm')}}</span>
                                    </template>
                                </el-table-column>
                            </el-table>
                        </div>
                    </div>
```

There are two el-table-box, which is associated with v-if="!specialAnnounce", the other is associated with v-if="specialAnnounce", how can I locate the first one with css selector?

I write

```
from selenium import webdriver
from selenium.webdriver.chrome.options import Options
from selenium.webdriver.common.by import By

# Configure Chrome options for headless mode
chrome_options = Options()
chrome_options.add_argument("--headless")  # Enable headless mode

# Set path to chromedriver executable
chromedriver_path = '/path/to/chromedriver'  # Replace with your actual path

# Create a new instance of the Chrome driver
driver = webdriver.Chrome(executable_path=chromedriver_path, options=chrome_options)

# Navigate to the desired web page
url ="http://www.cninfo.com.cn/new/commonUrl/pageOfSearch?url=disclosure/list/search" 
driver.get(url)  # Replace with the actual URL of the page

# Find the parent div element
parent_div = driver.find_element(By.CSS_SELECTOR, 'div.el-table-box[v-if="!specialAnnounce"]')
```

Then I get a nosuchelementexception

```
TimeoutException                          Traceback (most recent call last)
Cell In[2], line 21
     19 # Wait for the announcement elements to be visible
     20 wait = WebDriverWait(driver, 10)  # Adjust the timeout value as needed
---> 21 announcement_elements = wait.until(EC.visibility_of_all_elements_located((By.CSS_SELECTOR, "div.el-table-box[v-if$='!specialAnnounce']")))
     22 print(driver.page_source)
     23 # Extract the latest announcements within 2 hours

File ~\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python310\lib\site-packages\selenium\webdriver\support\wait.py:95, in WebDriverWait.until(self, method, message)
     93     if time.monotonic() > end_time:
     94         break
---> 95 raise TimeoutException(message, screen, stacktrace)

TimeoutException: Message:
```

Comment: I feel like your question is missing context. Regardless, here's a guess: `.el-table-box[v-if="!specialAnnounce"]`

Comment: `driver.find_element(By.CSS_SELECTOR, 'div.el-table-box')` should find only the first matching element (see [docs](https://selenium-python.readthedocs.io/locating-elements.html#locating-elements-by-css-selectors)). What does that return in your case? Zero elements, one, or more than one?

Comment: No nosuchelementexeception, but zero element

Comment: What happens when you `print(driver.page_source)`? Do you see the source with `<div class="el-table-box" ...>`?

Comment: I get a timeoutexception

Comment: It sounds like the page isn't being loaded, which would explain why `driver.find_element()` fails. Maybe the site is aware you're scraping it and is blocking you.

Comment: No, when I use announcement_title_element = wait.until(EC.visibility_of_element_located((By.CSS_SELECTOR, ".ahover a"))), I can successfully get annoucement titles.

Comment: Have you tried `wait.until()` for `.el-table-box`?

Comment: I get  [<selenium.webdriver.remote.webelement.WebElement (session="283374c58cbb5818429e334363d74a36", element="0A4B67E2A3AC5FE08A38327C2CBB77CE_element_8")>]  when I do parent_div = wait.until(EC.visibility_of_all_elements_located((By.CSS_SELECTOR, ".el-table-box")))
print(parent_div)

Comment: And what happens if you add a call to `driver.find_element(By.CSS_SELECTOR, 'div.el-table-box')` after the `wait.until()`?